# A problem relevant to find the function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Problem: Let $z=z(x,y)$ and $z'_{x}=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ and $z''_{yy}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$. Find $d^2z(0,1)$ and $z$.

This is my try: From above , I can compute $~z'_x,~z'_y,~dz~$ but I can't go to the last solution!

Comment: It is easy to find a solution on the form :$$z(x,y)=\frac12 y\ln(x^2+y^2)+x\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+c_1y+c_2$$ with arbitrary constant $c_1,c_2$. But what $d$ means in $dz$ and $d^2z$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you give me clear solution or give me a document about this ?

Comment: Not before you clarify the wording of your question. One cannot give you a relevant reference or document if one cannot understand what is your problem. It seems that you mix finite functions such as $z'_x,z'_y$ and infinitesimal term such as $dz$. Also $d^2z$ is a non-sens without a clear definition of the symbols used.

Comment: You wrote that you can compute $dz$. Can you write what you found for $dz$.